# I want to get other buttons' data-filter value at the same time

Tags: php, jquery

I got only `0` values in this code. When I write `this` inside the function I get 3 same values. Please help me with this problem. Thanks in advance

```js
$('#main_cat button, #price button, #color button').click(function() {
  // Get data of category
  var main_id = $("#main_cat button").data('filter');
  var price = $("#price button").data('filter');
  var color = $("#color button").data('filter');
  alert(main_id + " " + price + " " + color);

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/fetch",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      main_id: main_id,
      price: price,
      color: color
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#products_list').css("height", "455px");
      $('#products_list').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_cat" class="flex-w flex-l-m filter-tope-group m-tb-10">
  <button
    class="stext-106 cl6 hov1 bor3 trans-04 m-r-32 m-tb-5 how-active1"
    data-filter="0"
  >
    All Products
  </button>
  <?php foreach ($main_cat as $key =>
  $value) { ?>
  <button
    class="stext-106 cl6 hov1 bor3 trans-04 m-r-32 m-tb-5"
    data-filter="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"
  >
    <?php echo $value['name']; ?>
  </button>
  <?php } ?>
</div>

<div class="filter-col3 p-r-15 p-b-27">
  <div class="mtext-102 cl2 p-b-15">
    Color
  </div>

  <ul id="color">
    <li class="p-b-6">
      <button data-filter="0" class="filter-link stext-106 trans-04">
        All
      </button>
    </li>
    <?php foreach ($color as $key =>
    $value) { ?>
    <li class="p-b-6">
      <button
        data-filter="<?php echo $value['name'];?>"
        class="filter-link stext-106 trans-04"
      >
        <?php echo $value['name']; ?>
      </button>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="filter-col2 p-r-15 p-b-27">
  <div class="mtext-102 cl2 p-b-15">
    Price
  </div>

  <ul id="price">
    <li class="p-b-6">
      <button
        data-filter="0"
        class="filter-link stext-106 trans-04 filter-link-active"
      >
        All
      </button>
    </li>

    <li class="p-b-6">
      <button data-filter="1" class="filter-link stext-106 trans-04">
        $0.00 - $50.00
      </button>
    </li>

    <li class="p-b-6">
      <button data-filter="2" class="filter-link stext-106 trans-04">
        $50.00 - $100.00
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML. Click edit, then `[<>]` stack snippet - my guess is duplicate IDs and what looks like poor selectors

Comment: What is `$value['name']` here:  `<?php foreach ($color as $key => $value) { ?>`

Comment: @mplungjan black, white etc colors in db

Comment: @mplungjan  when I click buttons I got only 0 values all of them. Even I click other butons I only get 0.

Comment: I will not even try to help you further until you have posted relevant HTML I can run without guessing the values in your database!!!!!

Comment: @FikratDadashov My better approach for you is that you have to add a unique ID to each of your `button`, and then retrieve the value by initializing the `button` id.